# How to create a new jquery extension able to read dynamic inputs value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a new extension use, fn.extend

But, how to read all dynamic inputs value?  I can only get non dynamic inputs value...

```
$.fn.extend({
  test: function(){
    $(this).change(function (){
      alert($(this).val());
    });
  }
});

$(".test").test();
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One way I see is, you would have to tweak the `change` to handle dynamic elements using delegation,

```
$.fn.extend({
    test: function (selector) {
        $(document).on('change', selector, function (e) {   //use a static parent instead of $(document)
            alert(e.target.value);
        });
    }
});

$(".test").test();
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zqk5zzwx/)**

Comment: It is working, thank you.  But, it also get others object value because:

1.  $(".select").trigger("change");
2.  $(".select2").trigger("change");

Comment: Ohh, yes. I guess you would have to call `$(".test").test();` everytime after append

Comment: Oic... Noted with thanks.  :D  But it still a bit different result after binding into my JS file... Orz

Comment: I know why it happen the issue that i mentioned before.  It is because  $(".select").trigger("change");  is call after $(".test").test();